# htaccess redirect page on Magento multi store

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, redirect

We need to set up a htaccess redirect from one page to a directory, so this works:

```
Redirect 301 /page-name.html http://www.domain-01.co.uk/directory
```

But we have multiple domains set up through Magento so need to do this:

http://www.domain-01.co.uk/page-name.html redirect to http://www.domain-01.co.uk/directory
http://www.domain-02.co.uk/page-name.html redirect to http://www.domain-02.co.uk/directory

And these don't work:

```
Redirect 301 http://www.domain-01.co.uk/page-name.html http://www.domain-01.co.uk/directory
Redirect 301 http://www.domain-02.co.uk/page-name.html http://www.domain-02.co.uk/directory
```

or:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-01.co.uk/page-name.html
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-01.co.uk/directory [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-02.co.uk/page-name.html
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-02.co.uk/directory [R=301,L]
```

I've looked the documentation (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html#ToC1), but I can't see anything that relates to this.

The problem seems to me to be how do include a domain name in the first part of a redirect? Or am I asking the wrong question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it for *every* domains, you only have to do it like this

```
RewriteRule ^page-name\.html$ /directory [R=301,L]
```